# What is the need for having two different syntaxes for specializing data member of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, class-template, explicit-specialization

I was writing an example involving specialization of class template where I noticed that the standard allows two different syntax for specialization of a data member as shown below:

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};
template<> 
struct C<bool> {
    static int x;
};
//here we cannot write prefix template<> 
int C<bool>::x = 0;
```

As can be seen in the above example, we are not allowed to write the prefix `template<>` for defining the static data member `x`. And i understand this and have no problem with the above example. But when i modified the example to look like as shown below, i was surprised to see that we are allowed/required to write the prefix `template` for defining the static data member `x`:

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};

template<>  //here why is the use of prefix template<> allowed/required? Why standard mandates that we cannot omit this prefix template<> here but in the previous example we can omit it
int C<bool>::x = 0;
```

As can be seen in the above modified example, we are required to use the prefix `template<>` for defining the same static data member `x`. **My question is** that why is there a difference in syntax for defining the same data member `x` in the above two examples. That is why the standard requires the use of prefix `template<>` in the second example. Why can't we omit that prefix in the second example just like first example. *Does using the prefix `template<>` in the second example help solve some problem*(like some ambiguity or something else).

PS: Note that my question is **not about** which statement from the standard allows this usage(since i already know using the below given quoted statement from cppreference) but about the rationale for allowing these two syntaxes(one that uses `template<>` and one that doesn't).

---

I also came across the [following](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) and the code example given in the mentioned link that explain how this is allowed:

> When defining a member of an explicitly specialized class template outside the body of the class, the syntax template<> is not used, except if it's a member of an explicitly specialized member class template, which is specialized as a class template, because otherwise, the syntax would require such definition to begin with template required by the nested template .

The above quoted statement explains along with the example given there explains how the standard allows the above given examples in my question. But i am looking for a reason why is the prefix `template<>` mandated by the standard in the second example. Why standard doesn't allow the ommision of prefix `template<>` in the second example as in example 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explicit specialization** declaration of a class template is not a **template declaration**. [[Source]](https://www.amazon.in/Templates-Complete-Guide-David-Vandevoorde/dp/0321714121). This means that when we provide an explicit specialization for a class template, it behaves like an ordinary class.

Now we can apply this to the examples given in question.

**Example 1**

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};
//this is an specialization and so we must use template<> prefix
template<> 
struct C<bool> {
    static int x;
};
//this is just ordinary out of class definition of data member `x`. That is, this is not a specialization and so we don't need the prefix template<>
int C<bool>::x = 0;
```

In the above example, first we have provided an explicit specialization for `bool` of the class template `C` itself which behaves like an ordinary class(in the sense that it is not a template declaration). The `template<>` prefix is needed here because we were providing a specialization. Next, we provide an **ordinary out-of-class definition** of the static data member `x` of the specialization that we provided. But here we don't need the `template<>` prefix because this is not a specialization. This is just an ordinary out-of-class definition of a static data member.

**Example 2**

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};

template<>  // needed because this is not an ordinary out-of-class definition of data member x. Instead this is a specialization 
int C<bool>::x = 0;
```

In the above example, we have not provided any explicit specialization for class template C. Instead we are directly providing a specialization for the static data member `x`. This means that unlike example 1, here we are not providing an out-of-class definition of a static data member but instead we're providing a specialization. So in this case we need the `template<>` prefix.

##### TLDR

In example 1 `int C<bool>::x = 0;` is just an ordinary out-of-class definition of a static data member `x` and not a specialization, so we don't need the prefix `template<>` for this. Conversely, in example 2 `template<> int C<bool>::x = 0;` is a specialization of a static data member `x` and not an ordinary out-of-class definition. So in this case(example 2) the prefix `template<>` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

They aren't different syntaxes for the same thing, they are different syntaxes for different things.

The first specializes the entire struct, including all its members.
That is, the specialization `C<bool>::x` is already implied by the struct specialization, and you're not allowed to specialize twice.
`int C<bool>::x = 0;` is a regular definition of the static member in that specialization.

The second only specializes the member, not the struct, and defines it at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The first

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};

// This is the template specialisation for bool and all struct members
template<> 
struct C<bool> {
    static int x;
};

// This is the extraneous template specialisation for bool
// and the single struct member, already specialized above - error
// template<> 
// int C<bool>::x = 0;
```

The modified first example

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};

// This is the template specialisation for bool and the single struct member
template<> 
int C<bool>::x = 0;

// This is the extraneous template specialisation for bool
// and all struct members, one of them is already specialized above - error
// template<> 
// struct C<bool> {
//    static int x;
// };
```

The second

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};

// This is the unique template specialisation for bool - ok
template<>
int C<bool>::x = 0;
```

Another example

```
template<typename T >
struct C {
    static int x;
};

// This is the template specialisation for bool
template<> 
struct C<bool> {
    static int x;
};

// This is another template socialisation for int - ok
template<>
int C<int>::x = 0;
```

Comment: I already know this. My question is not about this. The first example in your answer won't work. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KaM3xr714) as shown in clang error.

Comment: If you know this, why do you ask about the error of the double declared template specialisation?

Comment: The first example in your answer doesn't work with clang. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KaM3xr714) So are you saying that we're allowed to write the prefix `template<>` in my first example as well?

Comment: I marked it `error` in the comment.

Comment: But you don't explain why is it `extraneous` in the first example but not in the second. That is what i am asking. If you add some explanation in your answer, then it would be better.

Comment: I've extended the first example, should be more clear now. The error is caused by redefinition.